# Change the `list` attribute of an <input> in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/f4k458yg/)

Trying to change the input ID: List from A to B, but its not changing.

I am planning on creating many datalist with PHP from MySQL,

Select Company name, and see their employees in next list.

HTML:

```
change List:
<input type="text" id="List" list="A">
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="A" value="B">
<br>
<button onclick="change()">
  Change List
</button>

<datalist id="A">
  <option value="None">
    <option value="1">
      <option value="2">
</datalist>

<datalist id="B">
  <option value="3">
    <option value="4">
</datalist>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function change() {
  console.log("Started");
  var x = document.getElementById('A').value;
  document.getElementById('List').list = x;

  var check = document.getElementById('List').list

  if (check === x) {
    console.log("Complete");
  } else {
    console.log("Failed");
  }
}
```

Thank you, its now working.

[Working](https://jsfiddle.net/f4k458yg/1/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to the Mozilla Developer Network docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties), the `list` attribute is read-only and actually returns a reference to a DOM element (like a `<datalist>`):

> `list` [**Read only**]
>
> `HTMLElement object`: Returns the element pointed by the `list` attribute.
>   The property may be `null` if no HTML element found in the same tree.

Thus, you need to use `setAttribute` to set the list by `id`, and then use `element.list.id` to retrieve the correct value for `check`.

```js
function change() {
  console.log("Started")
  var x = document.getElementById('A').value
  
  document.getElementById('List').setAttribute('list', x)

  var check = document.getElementById('List').list.id

  if (check === x) {
    console.log("Complete");
  } else {
    console.log("Failed");
  }
}
```

```html
change List:
<input type="text" id="List" list="A">
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="A" value="B">
<br>
<button onclick="change()">
  Change List
</button>

<datalist id="A">
  <option value="None">
    <option value="1">
      <option value="2">
</datalist>

<datalist id="B">
  <option value="3">
    <option value="4">
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `list` is not a standard attribute, direct refering with the `dot` notation won't work. Use `getAttribute` and `setAttribute` functions instead.

```js
function change() {
  console.log("Started");
  var x = document.getElementById('C'),
      list = document.getElementById('List'),
      check = list.getAttribute(list);
      list.setAttribute('list', x);

  if (check === x.getAttribute('list')) {
    console.log("Complete");
  } else {
    console.log("Failed");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="List" list="A">
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="C" value="B">
<br>
<button onclick="change()">
  Change List
</button>

<datalist id="A">
  <option value="None">
    <option value="1">
      <option value="2">
</datalist>

<datalist id="B">
  <option value="3">
    <option value="4">
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript

```
function change() {
     
   document.getElementById('List').setAttribute('list', document.getElementById('A').id);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the `value` property on the dom element

```
  document.getElementById('List').value = x;

  var check = document.getElementById('List').value

  if (check === x) {
    console.log("Complete");
  } else {
    console.log("Failed");
    console.log(check);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer... OP is trying to manipulate the `list` attribute, not  the `value` attribute.

Comment: Funny, I could have swore the title was chage the input list value of the OP

Comment: My apologies; I took a look at the edits and see how the original title might have been misleading. That's probably why I decided to edit it. In the posted code, though, it is apparent that OP is trying to get/set the `input.list` property.